# How to use two different BroadcastReceivers of two different Apps with same Intent-filter?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, sms

I have two different apps. Both of them has `BroadcastReceiver` class registered in `AndroidManifest.xml` with same `intent-filter`. The `intent-filter` is `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED`. Both apps listen to incoming sms messages and do some according to SMS. Now my problem is the apps works well when only one installed. If I installed both the apps in my mobile when an SMS receives one app crashes. If I force stop anyone then the other app works fine. How to use two different `BroadcastRecivers` of two different Apps with same Intent-filter?

Stack Trace is

```
09-24 12:58:13.549  19882-19882/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.realtech.securetracknew, PID: 19882
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.realtech.securetracknew.LogReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2580)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.realtech.securetracknew.LogReceiver.onReceive(Unknown Source)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2573)

at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:151)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My `onReceive` method was

```
    @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION)) {
        Bundle intentExtras = intent.getExtras();
        if (intentExtras != null) {
            Object[] sms = (Object[]) intentExtras.get(smsBundle);
            for (int i = 0; i < sms.length; i++) {
                SmsMessage smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) sms[i]);
                smsBody = smsMessage.getMessageBody();
                smsAddress = smsMessage.getOriginatingAddress();
                try {
                    smsFrom = smsAddress.substring(3, 13);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            Toast.makeText(context,smsBody,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the crash that you get? I believe both of your apps should be able to receive the intent

Comment: It's `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: I will need the whole stacktrace.

Comment: @hoomi I added my stacktrace

Comment: Can you add the code for `com.realtech.securetracknew.LogReceiver.onReceive` as well?

Comment: ok. I'm adding my code.

Comment: I have added my code @hoomi

Comment: Can you try to find out on which line it is crashing? (either using the debugger or logs)

Comment: @hoomi after the app crashes I got something like this 09-24 13:28:46.677      711-727/? I/WindowManager﹕ Gaining focus: Window{42b94ca8 u0 Application Error: com.realtech.securetracknew}
and 09-24 13:28:58.498      711-727/? I/WindowManager﹕ Losing focus: Window{42b94ca8 u0 Application Error: com.realtech.securetracknew EXITING}

Comment: Did you find out on which line it crashes? Does it even get to `intent.getAction().equals(ACTION)`

Comment: Yes, it receives SMS. `09-24 13:48:56.953  27988-27988/? D/ActivityThread﹕ BDC-Calling onReceive: intent=Intent { act=android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED flg=0x8000010 cmp=com.realtech.securetracknew/.LogReceiver (has extras) }, ordered=true, receiver=com.realtech.securetracknew.LogReceiver@41d88e00
`

Comment: You are still not telling me on which line it crashes. Can you put some logs after each line and see after which line the crash happens

Comment: Please post the code for the other `BroadcastReceiver`.